# Material ui Icon inside i18 text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, i18next

Is it possible to use material ui icons inside the i18 translation text?

I have installed the library and imported to the parent file and i put this line in my language json file but it wont work:

```
{ "text": "some text <ErrorOutlineIcon /> ..."}
```

it only renders "some text ..."

Thanks

Comment: It is store as a string that is the reason it is not working. By the way, you can render the icon outside the i18 parser. Icons don't have language or translation.

Comment: @RajendranNadar i need that icon in the middle of my text, thats why i am putting it there

Comment: Do this `{translation1} <Icon /> {translation2}` or use back-ticks `{ "text": `some text ${<ErrorOutlineIcon />} some more text `} ` not sure about the 2nd method you can try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use [interpolation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation) with [Trans component](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component)

```
import { useTranslations, Trans } from 'react-i18next';
 
...

const { t } = useTranslation();

...

<Trans t={t} i18nextKey="text">
{{ leftText: "This is on the left side" }} <YourIcon /> {{rightText: "This is on the right side"}}
</Trans>
```

and in your translation json:

```
"text" : {{leftText}} <1/> {{rightText}}
```

I haven't tested this, but you can refer to the documentation linked above.